# How to do string substitution for dictionary values

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to the dict's value for key `"_string"` to be formatted like `"tags:6586"`

```
tagid=[6586,6573,6570]

for tid in tagid:
    
    t_id="tags:{}".format(tid)
    
    query={"query": {"_and": [{"_string":"t_id"}]}}
    print (query)
```

returns

```
{'query': {'_and': [{'_string': 't_id'}]}}

{'query': {'_and': [{'_string': 't_id'}]}}

{'query': {'_and': [{'_string': 't_id'}]}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `query={"query": {"_and": [{"_string":"t_id"}]}}` replace `"t_id"` by `str(t_id)`:

```
query={"query": {"_and": [{"_string": t_id}]}}
```

You want to put there the string representation of your variable `t_id`, not the string `"t_id"`.